# insert or update records of group values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, relational-database

I have  purchase and stock tables. It is commonly known that a product may have different price in different time.So I would like to create a stock table. the stock table will show each product summery. Here my purchase table

```
 purchase_id product_id cost_price quantity date
 1            127       300         50      2013-07-25
 2            126       100         50      2013-07-25
 3            127       350         100     2013-07-26
 4            126       50          50      2013-07-26
 5            127       250         20      2013-07-27
 6            128       300         50      2013-07-27
```

So I want to see each product summery like average cost,total cost, last date cost, total quantity etc in each row of my stock table. Here my stock table

```
 stock_id product_id  cost_avg__price  cost_last_date__price  total_pur_quant total_stock quant
 1        126         75               50                     100              80
 2        127         300              250                    270              250
 3        128         300              300                    50               50
```

How can I insert or update group value in stock table when add new purchase in purchase table. 
 *Note that anyone can say build VIEW for stock. but I need update information in future. suppose quantity will reduce when product sale.*

Comment: I was going to suggest you use a view and create a trigger to handle updates. However, it looks like MySQL doesn't do instead of triggers. So you'll want triggers on your purchase table to update your stock table.

Comment: but how can i handle view to table using trigger

Comment: MySQL can't do instead of triggers, so you can't. Here's what you do want: Create the two tables. Create Triggers after insert,update,delete on purchase table. These triggers will update stock table.